Need to replace an SMD fuse marked "o". Image available
I can't find a replacement of this SMD fuse on the internet. I'm trying to fix my white screen monitor issue like in this video:
https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=HxusdMp4Nko


@Chester Gillon: Question re-opened. The close reason is not sensible. While his WORDING says "I can't find a place to buy" that is NOT what he means. He is asking the fuse type and value. The close reasons MAY be better than the reason shown, but useful comment is needed for a complete newcomer. There are two useful answer pre close. So ... . RM

@Andy Aka -  please see above comment.

@Ralph - please see above comment.

Both the Littelfuse 437 series fuses and Multicomp SMD fuses use letter O for a 2.5A fuse. They both are rated for 32V.
If you can idetify the package size and find more data sheets that say "O" means 2.5A then it's the likely answer.
But, if your fuse blew up, the fuse blew up for a reason, and if the reason is still there, the new fuse will blow up too.
Also, the fuse may not even be the problem, unless you have verified the fuse is blown, because the same effect would be that the power supply that feeds the fuse won't start.
So the fuse may not even be the problem. Don't randomly change a fuse because someone else changed a fuse on a Youtube video. You may have a different issue and the fuse is not it.

Thank you for your response, yes there is a reason, a transistor shorted like in the video I linked, I believe I have the same problem since I'm getting the same signs from tests applied in the video, I'm yet to remove the transistor and double check it isolated. Regarding the size package, the guy in the video used a big fuse "bM" 1206, half an Amp as he stated an it worked for him. Want do you think? And can you identify the fuse he used so I can buy it? Thank you very much.

@Moltu I think it is not wise to replace a fuse with a different rating. And questions about what to buy and from where are off topic.

The place where i am, no one fixes these things! And I also can't afford a new monitor right now. So I'm looking for solutions. I have a multimeter and I really believe it's the same problem in the video. All I need now is a way to know the best replacement fuse for my fuse that I know nothing about! Especially When I confirm that the transistor is faulty, then the only hurdler between me and fixing the monitor is that very tiny fuse. The fuse on the board is much smaller than the 1206 package size (kindly, see time 3:13 in the video to see the fuse and its replacement by that guy)

@Moltu Best replacement fuse is subjective. Just put any fuse there. If it is rated too low, it will burn. If it is rated too high, fuse will be OK and something else in the circuit wil burn. You can use any fuse you can find for testing. If the original was a 2.5V fuse then put a 2.5A fuse but nobody can guess if it was a 2.5A fuse.

so someone with the same issue stated that it's a 0603 smd fuse and they managed to replace it successfully. In your first reply you asked for package size, I think this is it right?

@Moltu yes but you can use any fuse such as a car fuse or mains fuse if you solder some wires.

I get what you're saying, the fuse is a security measure to protect the circuit and that's very important. What do you advice me to do?

@Moltu Your original question about identifying the fuse details is answered. What you want or can do with that info is up to you. Chances are the people making those Youtube videos you are watching also do not know what fuse it is and what a good replacement is either. Maybe find a fuse on some old PC motherboard if you are unable to buy a new one.

Thank you very much for your help. Someone tested with "FUSE 2.5A 32V SMD 0603" and it worked for them i will go with that fuse myself.

I don't think you have enough information to replace it.
Fuses have speeds (slow/fast) and current ratings. If you know neither, a replacement is likely to be incorrect. "O" or "0" can't tell anything since if it's "0" then clearly the current rating can't be 0 amperes or any current in any direction would blow it.
I guess the best option is to use whatever knowledge you have to estimate what the current going through that fuse might be, and pick a slow fuse clearly above that so it wouldn't blow too easily.
If the fuse has blown, it's likely it has blown for a reason, and if the reason is still existing, your new fuse can blow too.

Thank you for your response. I added some context in my reply to the first comment. Kindly, take a look. Thanks again and apprentice your help
